# GWT GoogleMaps: Display KML Name on Map

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3, kml

My end goal is to display arbitrary text on a GoogleMap using the GoogleMaps v3 GWT API. I *think* the way to do that is through KML. If that's not the way to go, I'd love to hear other approaches (other than displaying the text as images). If KML is the way to go, then I wonder what I'm doing wrong:

I'm trying to load this example KML file into a test GoogleMap through GWT: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml

The main tag in that file I care about is this one:

```
  <Placemark>
    <name>Simple placemark</name>
    <description>Attached to the ground. Intelligently places itself at the
      height of the underlying terrain.</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
```

When I render that KML file on Google Earth, the name (Simple placemark) is displayed directly on the map. Hooray!

However, when I render that KML file on GoogleMaps, the name is not displayed on the map, and only shows up in an InfoWindow when I click on the placemark. Everything else seems to display fine, except no text is rendered directly on the map, which is my entire goal.

I've included the example map code I'm using, and I'm hoping there's a way to tell the GoogleMap to display the name, or really any text, on the map directly.

```
package com.test.client;

import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader;
import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader.AjaxLoaderOptions;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.GoogleMap;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.KmlLayer;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeId;

public class GwtTest implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
        options.setOtherParms("sensor=false");
        Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createMap();
            }
        };
        AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
    }

    public void createMap() {

        MapOptions mapOpts = MapOptions.create();
        mapOpts.setZoom(4);
        mapOpts.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mapOpts.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        final GoogleMap map = GoogleMap.create(Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOpts);

        KmlLayer kmlLayer = KmlLayer.create("https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml");
        kmlLayer.setMap(map);
    }
}
```

If there simply isn't a way to render text on a GoogleMap, is there an "official" place that says so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody stumbling upon this question, what I eventually ended up doing was using Google's chart API: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons

This allows you to dynamically create images using arguments passed into a URL. Then you can just use that URL to create a MarkerImage or GroundOverlay:

```
MarkerImage mi = MarkerImage.create("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=000000|16|h|FFFFFF|_|Example");
MarkerOptions mo = MarkerOptions.create();
mo.setIcon(mi);
mo.setPosition(LatLng.create(37.1918, -95.8892));
Marker m = Marker.create(mo);
m.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

The option on the [official place](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays) for this is to use a [Custom Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays). Their example uses an img element, but change this to a div element and then set the innerHTML or similar to show your text over the map.

You should be able to use the sample javascript code to help you implement this in GWT - extend the OverlayView class from the Google GWT wrapper library etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the official Google GWT wrapper for GoogleMaps from gwt-google-apis: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/. I can display an image on the map using a GroundOverlay, but what I'm trying to do is display arbitrary text. The GroundOverlay only supports images, and I'd like to avoid that if at all possible. Alternatively, if there's an official source saying that text isn't supported in GWT GoogleMaps, that'll satisfy the higher-ups as well...

Comment: The Google GWT wrapper contains the OverlayView class, use that to do a Custom Overlay (which is what you use to overlay text).